# my react state variable is not updating while using websocket

Tags: reactjs, react-state

hello I'm using websocket to get my data, the problem is that when i tried to save the data into my state in react component is re rendering as expected but my data is not saved on state variable

````
export default function ResultPageContent() {
  const processed = useSelector((state) => state.processedSlice);
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const fetchData = (links) => {
    const socket = new webSocket("ws://localhost:5000/");
    socket.onopen = () => {
      socket.send(JSON.stringify(links));
    };

    socket.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
      const tempData = JSON.parse(data);
      setData(tempData);
    };
    socket.onclose = () => {};
  };
  const renderContent = () => {
    if (data.per < 100) {
      return <CircularProgressWithLabel value={data.per} />;
    }
  };
 if (processed) {
    console.log("links", links);
    fetchData(links);
    dispatch(MAKE_FALSE());
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Paper
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          background: theme.palette.background.default,
          marginBottom: "50px",
        }}
        className={classes.root}
      >
        {renderContent()}
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: I cannot see `fetchData` being referenced anywhere, suggesting it is not being called at all. Is there something missing from this example?

Comment: updated a example

Comment: i got the issue  dispatch(MAKE_FALSE()) is creating a issue